# How to add a Nuget Package badge in the latest version of VSTS

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, nuget-package, badge

I've been trying to add a package badge to my Readme.md file in my code repository, something like this:

[image]

I've been following this article:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/artifacts/vsts-package-badges?view=vsts

I'm using the latest version of VSTS and don't seem to have the "Create Badge" option, see screen shot below:

[image]

I'm accessing my packages using this url in VSTS:

https://.visualstudio.com/Platform/_packaging

How do I enable the package badge for my internal nuget feeds in this version of VSTS?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to go back to old navigation menu and add the badge from there?

Comment: I did - still can't see it!  Are you thinking it might be permissions?

Comment: Ah, I hadn't enabled the "Enable package badges" function in setting, that's it working now!  Doh! :)

Comment: Great :) also in the new navigation menu?

Comment: It was indeed - will add a screen shot now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting for package badges needed to be enabled, see below:

[image]

Click the "Settings" cog on your feed page (https://[projectname].visualstudio.com/[projectname]/_packaging page).